# VirtualBox Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 Running on Windows 7: Can't access web app running on port 8080 from host

Tags: server, virtualbox

•I am running a test of "react-jPlayer" on a Ubuntu test server in VirtualBox.
•The app is running sucessfully on port 8080.
 
•I Verified this by opening a new terminal window with tmux and entering "curl localhost:8080". It loaded the source code of the jPlayer test sucessfully.
•Ubuntu VirtualBox is running on a **bridged Ethernet adapter** (I thought this made all ports accessible between VirtualBox and host).
•When I open the server local I.P. from my host PC http://172.16.1.71:80 my Apache default index loads successfully.
•when I open http://172.16.1.71:8080 from the Windows 7 host PC the browser does not connect to the server.

I am very new at this.

More info on react-jPlayer & my issue: https://github.com/jplayer/react-jPlayer-examples/issues/3

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Attach the output of `ifconfig` of ubuntu

Comment: Hello!
Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I will do my best to follow your advice. I am very new at this and would greatly appreciate if you could explain in more detail how to use ifconfig to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a bridged connection in Virtualbox, a direct connection is made between your VM and the network. Your VM will be assigned a diffrent IP address from you host and therefore you should use that IP address. 
The command ifconfig should output the IP address of your VM. 
E.g. If the output of ifconfig for eth0 includes 'inet addr: 172.16.1.72' then you should connect to 172.16.1.72:8080.